# How to get the user environment details in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

So, For some audit purpose i should track the below details from user whoever connected to hosted web application.

- Operating system:
- Browser:
- Estimated location:
- Service Provier:
- Domain:
- IP address:
- MachineName:
- UserName

To get IP Address, MeachineName, UserName i tried with below code.

```
var userIpAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
var MachineName = HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Server.MachineName;
var UserName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Edit:

```
var Browser = Request.Browser.Browser;
var OperatingSystem = Request.Browser.Platform;
```

So how get the remaining field values?

Comment: Surely Google can answer some of this. This question is essentially five "how can I determine X about the user?" questions in one, you should research them separately then come back with more specific questions about each.

Comment: I think client side script can get things like operating system and browser more reliably than server side code, so you can grab those with JavaScript and send to the server via AJAX request in order to log it.

Comment: As @Darin summarizes below, you can't get most of these parameters, without assumptions. I could be using curl scripts to scrap your site, fooling your webserver that the user-agent is something legitimate. Privacy laws are also something that you should look at.

Comment: @millimoose, I didn't understand why you closed it ?

Comment: @Alex, I didn't understand why you closed it ?

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi I explained why, I have *several* reasons in fact. First: It's an omnibus question, since each of those parameters might have to be determined in a different way. (Reverse DNS, geolocation...) Omnibus questions are problematic since no single answer may be the "best" on all of their components, so it's better to split it up into multiple ones. Second: after splitting up, you should research those subquestions yourself first. Just typing up "how to determine location" makes Google suggest adding "from IP" and "based on IP", so you should first investigate those options.

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi And third: there's a vagueness problem, in that you haven't really explained the field values. Most are obvious enough, but it's not clear what the "service provider" and "domain" are. (Provider of which service? Etc.) This in and of itself is a problem salvageable by editing, but since I saw the question as worth closing (i.e. restarting from scratch) anyway, why bother making it marginally less problematic.

Answer (score 1):

> So how get the remaining field values?

You can't. Those values are never sent to your server as part of the HTTP request.

And don't be fooled into thinking that `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Server.MachineName` gives you the machine name of your client. This gives you the machine name of the server. You cannot get the machine name of the client.

Comment: what about `Request.Browser.Platform` for operating system?

Comment: Completely unreliable. This information might or might not be sent from the client.

Comment: But still is there any chance to get?? For example when you change the password in FaceBook they will send mail with all the above values.

Comment: You could parse the `User-Agent` request header. That's the best you could get.